# how to parent multiple new objects to rigid body objects?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

i made tracks for my tank. These track parts are just thick planes. Now i want to make them more interesting with more geometry. Inset/extrude etc.

[image]

So then i wanna exchange them by hiding the rigid body track parts and parent the new "designed" parts to the rigid body objects.
For one object, this is pretty easy, i copy with shift-d, hide the rigid body object and parent the new object to the rb object. Then i design the new object in edit mode and give it a new material.
But i don't wanna do that for 200+ track parts.
Is there an easier way to do that?

Of course the "new" objects should follow the animation the tracks already have.

Here is what i tried:

if i just "link object data", the animation/transformation is lost - that's what i don't want.

[image]

here is the blend file before:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtnorvl66admu2z/link%20data%20probl.blend?dl=0

here is the blend file after:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0j927tmwtifijat/link%20data%20probl%20after.blend?dl=0

As Gordon commented right: the files were made with the newest alpha version of GN - so you might have to download them to open the files properly.

Comment: I know you are always using the latest alpha versions, but maybe you should hint to that in your question. As you know, this site is focusing on official stable releases and if someone simply tries to open the file with 3.5.1, Blender crashes. Now I cannot look into your file - so I'm not sure what kind of animations/transformations you are using. But when I select two objects and choose Ctrl+L > _Link Object Data_, both keep their individual animations.

Comment: thanks, i update my question

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: was that comment on a "general" use of ctrl-l of did you really try that with my file...?

Comment: As I said, I cannot look into your file. That's why I wrote "I'm not sure what kind of animations/transformations you are using". In general this should be no problem: [link object data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KJAhy4MzQtRzG5RllUk6tkn_oTLnfb43/view?usp=sharing) (keyframed animation) or this: [linked rigid bodies](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hiC6VMS4HctjcWswMhES53YEU9pWRysQ/view?usp=sharing) (cached rigid body simulation).